# How to know if the DELETE query really deletes a row ,using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am passing a `DELETE` query to mysql using `PDO` statements. I want to know, whether the  query really deletes a row or not? I try to use return value of `$stmt->execute()`

```
function delete(){
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE id= :id");
    $stmt->bindValue(':id',$_POST[id]);

    var_dump($stmt->execute());
}
```

But This gives always `true`, even no row is deleted. This gives true even if I don't post any value Or even post same value again and again. May be because query is successful with 0 row deleted , so return value of `$stmt->execute()` does not help.

So Is There any other way in `PDO` to know whether any row is really deleted or not, more specifically I want to be sure that only one row was deleted.

So i want something like this

```
function delete(){
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE id= :id");
    $stmt->bindValue(':id',$_POST[id]);
    $stmt->execute();
    if($rowdeleted == 1){ echo "success";}
    else{echo "failure";}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Statement suppose to return number of columns affected by query. At least in postgres.

Comment: [PDOStatement::rowCount()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: i get it , I thought `rowcount()` only works  for select staetement

Comment: @beginner. I have provided with the explanations about the process how to get the affected rows after the operations and some sample code along with the output. Have a try and share thoughts about your view. Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using PDO then you need the [rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) method.
In case of mysqli you need the [affected rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php)

Answer (score 19):

### Explanation

In order to know how many rows have been affected for the last operation during the select and Delete you have to `GET THE ROW COUNT` after the execution of the code.

**Conditions:**

- If the count is greater than `0` - It means the code has affected some operations.
- If the count does no return greater than `0` - It means that there is no records to match in the WHERE Clause.

### Examples

`PDOStatement::rowCount` - Returns the number of rows affected by the last SQL statement

`PDOStatement::rowCount()` returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.

If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.

**Sample Code:**

```
<?php
/* Delete all rows from the FRUIT table */
$del = $dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM fruit');
$del->execute();

/* Return number of rows that were deleted */
print("Return number of rows that were deleted:\n");
$count = $del->rowCount();
print("Deleted $count rows.\n");
?>
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Return number of rows that were deleted:
Deleted 9 rows.
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: It was very simple then i thought , i knew about `rowcount()` but i thought it works only for select statement , but happy to know that this method works for all queries , thanks for your broad explaination

Comment: Welcome. Happy that you have understood. :)

Comment: Please justify for the negative vote..

Comment: I fail to see how the link you posed is related to the question.

Comment: @YourCommonSense. I thought he can use this as an alternative method to get the count from the PDO statements..

Comment: @YourCommonSense. If so it is not needed i may remove it. But YourCommonSense please mention since negative votes are made and we go in search of reasons why that has been made.

Comment: by the link you posted it is offered to use count(*) query. How on the earth one could use this statement to know the result of delete query?

Answer (score 0):

You could try somethign like this:

```
if($stmt[0]->rowCount() > 0)
{ 
echo "success";
}
else{
echo "failure";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick is to check the number of row affected

```
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
```